# Is there a function to write/export values of list-/class items?

Tags: vb.net

From an external application data is extracted and written to a list with several sublist items, here is an example narrowed down to the main list creation:

```
Public Class clMain
    Public lsLevel_1 As New List(Of clLevel_1)
End Class

Public Class clLevel_1
    Public sgName As String
    Public lsLevel_2 As New List(Of clLevel_2)
End Class

Public Class clLevel_2
    Public sgName As String
    Public lsLevel_3 As New List(Of clLevel_3)
End Class

Public Class clLevel_3
    Public sgName As String
    Public sgComment As String
End Class

Module Code
    Sub Main()
        Dim lv_clMain As clMain = New clMain
        For lv_i16Level_1 = 10 To 11
            Dim lv_clLevel_1 As New clLevel_1
            lv_clLevel_1.sgName = "Level 1: " & lv_i16Level_1
            For lv_i16Level_2 = 20 To 21
                Dim lv_clLevel_2 As New clLevel_2
                lv_clLevel_2.sgName = "Level 2: " & lv_i16Level_2
                For lv_i16Level_3 = 30 To 31
                    Dim lv_clLevel_3 As New clLevel_3
                    lv_clLevel_3.sgName = "Level 3: " & lv_i16Level_3
                    lv_clLevel_2.lsLevel_3.Add(lv_clLevel_3)
                Next
                lv_clLevel_1.lsLevel_2.Add(lv_clLevel_2)
            Next
            lv_clMain.lsLevel_1.Add(lv_clLevel_1)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Once the list has been "filled", I would like to write/export the values to a file. What would be a good approach for this tasks? I think creating a function with `lv_clMain` as parameter. But as `lv_clMain` is not a collection type, and it can contain several entries of `lsLevel_1` I am somewhat lost about the correct approach.

Comment: Is there something that serializing the class with json/xml isn't able to do?

Comment: I did not know about serializing, so it was more me who was not able. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user [Hursey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2117435/hursey), I found a solution using XML serialisation.

```
Function SerializeXml(ByVal obData As Object, ByVal sgFileName As String, tyData As Type)
    Dim obXmlSerializer As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(tyData)
    Dim obSW As System.IO.TextWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(sgFileName)
    obXmlSerializer.Serialize(obSW, obData)
    obSW.Close()
End Function
```